# Any Mobile Theme Switcher - Theme not complete (Stylesheet missing)

Tags: themes, mobile

I am trying to install the theme "Any Mobile Theme Switcher" on Wordpress 3.2.1, in order to give my Site a different layout, depending on where it is displayed.

Installation succeeds, but in the the "Themes" view of the dashobard, I cannot select the theme, it says rather: any-mobile-theme-switcher - Stylesheet missing.

What can I do?

Theme:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/any-mobile-theme-switcher/

Comment: Please link to the extension you are talking about. Also it's probably question best aimed at its developer.

Answer (score 0):

That is a *plugin*, not *theme*. It should be installed and managed as such through `Plugins` menu or putting it into appropriate plugins folder.